# How to subset a 1-d array using a boolean 1-d array in numba decorated function?

Tags: numpy, numba

I gotta say, numba seems to be usable only in extremely simplistic use cases carefully designed to be presented in talks

I can run the following code just fine:

```
def rt(hi):
    for i in hi:
        hi_ = i == hi
        t = hi[hi_]
    return None
rt(np.array(['a','b','c','d'],dtype='U'))
```

But, when i decorate the above code with `njit`:

```
@njit
def rt(hi):
    for i in hi:
        hi_ = i == hi
        t = hi[hi_]
    return None
rt(np.array(['a','b','c','d'],dtype='U'))
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-eadef1d0ecee> in <module>
      5         t = hi[hi_]
      6     return None
----> 7 rt(np.array(['a','b','c','d'],dtype='U'))

~/miniconda/envs/IndusInd_credit_cards_collections_scorecard_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    418                 e.patch_message(msg)
    419 
--> 420             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    421         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    422             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

~/miniconda/envs/IndusInd_credit_cards_collections_scorecard_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    359                 raise e
    360             else:
--> 361                 raise e.with_traceback(None)
    362 
    363         argtypes = []

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> getitem(array([unichr x 1], 1d, C), Literal[bool](False))
 
There are 22 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 20 did not match due to:
      Overload of function 'getitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
        With argument(s): '(array([unichr x 1], 1d, C), bool)':
       No match.
      - Of which 1 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'GetItemBuffer.generic': File: numba/core/typing/arraydecl.py: Line 162.
        With argument(s): '(array([unichr x 1], 1d, C), bool)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypeError: unsupported array index type bool in [bool]
  raised from /home/sarthak/miniconda/envs/IndusInd_credit_cards_collections_scorecard_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/typing/arraydecl.py:68
      - Of which 1 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'GetItemBuffer.generic': File: numba/core/typing/arraydecl.py: Line 162.
        With argument(s): '(array([unichr x 1], 1d, C), Literal[bool](False))':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypeError: unsupported array index type Literal[bool](False) in [Literal[bool](False)]
  raised from /home/sarthak/miniconda/envs/IndusInd_credit_cards_collections_scorecard_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/typing/arraydecl.py:68

During: typing of intrinsic-call at <ipython-input-34-eadef1d0ecee> (5)

File "<ipython-input-34-eadef1d0ecee>", line 5:
def rt(hi):
    <source elided>
        hi_ = i == hi
        t = hi[hi_]
        ^
```

How to subset a 1-d array using a boolean 1-d array in numba decorated function?

Comment: talks are seldom enough to get you started, much less proficient, in any language or package.

Comment: The indexing method is the same. The error says it's not implemented for arrays of unicode characters. I guess it's hard for Numba developers to catch up with all the available Python features, so they prioritize number crunching.